# Solid conducting sphere, its material, electric field and electric potential

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, potential, conductors

I have tried reading multiple post from stackexchange google, but still cannot figure it out:

lets say if i wrote "A solid sphere has charge distributed uniformly throughout..."

can i conclude that sphere is not made up of metal?

in this statement, I find things to be paradoxical. out of all these statements, that i equally find it inaccurate?

for example "sphere is not made up of metal?" , charged can be distributed uniformly in any kind: like in charged conductor (excess charges go to the surface but non-excess/remaining one which was present initially still remains), uncharged conductor(can have uniform charged distribution, can also have non-uniform charge distribution) or non-conductor/insulator (because we know that unlike conducting sphere that has charge distributed only on the surface, non-conducting sphere tends to distribute charges throughout the volume of sphere), so not enough information for "sphere is not made up of metal?"

please let me know if any of my statement is wrong and help me approach this concept, and clear all my doubts, misunderstanding, knowledge gaps.

Answer (score 1):

Your incorrect interpretation is in the following statement:

> like in [a] charged conductor (excess charges go to the surface but non-excess one which was present initially still remains)

I'm not sure what you mean by "non-excess charge", but the general result is that *there is no net charge in the interior of a conductor*.  It's true that on a microscopic level there are equal amounts of positive and negative charges inside an electrically neutral piece of metal;  perhaps that's what you mean by "non-excess charge"?

But when the question asks about a "charge distributed uniformly throughout", it is referring to a "*non-zero net* charge distributed throughout".  And such a charge distribution cannot exist inside a conductor.

---

***Edit:*** *the quotes below were included in a previous version of the question, so I am leaving these answers here for posterity; but they are not relevant to the question as currently posed.*

Beyond this, you have a few other misconceptions I can identify:

> electric potential is not constant on the surface with respect to what? infinity(outside the sphere) ?, center? earth's ground?

Whether or not the electric potential is constant on some surface doesn't depend on your reference point.  If I redefine my reference point, that just adds a constant to all of my potential values everywhere in space.  That means that (for example) if $V = -3$ volts everywhere on the surface of the sphere in my old system, and I redefine my potential so that it adds $+5$ volts to all potential values everywhere in space, then we have $V' = +2$ volts everywhere on the surface in my new system and it's still constant.

> V(at surface) is constant in uncharged conductor and not in charged conductor.

$V$ on the surface is constant for both charged and uncharged conductors.  This follows from the fact that the electric field inside the conductor must be zero.

> i know electric field inside a metal conductor is always 0 because charges redistribute themselves to create internal electric field and oppose the external electric field to make E = 0 inside... but usually questions(like this for example) dont specify whether external electric field is present or not. what if external electric field is absent? how will they make E = 0? or will it won't be 0?

In electrostatics, the electric field inside a conductor (charged or neutral) is always zero, regardless of whether or not there is an external field.

> there is another notion of symmetry. the question doesnt specify whether sphere is symmetric or not, because it can have non-symmetric but uniformly distributed charge. i think when charge is uniformly distributed, it is ALWAYS symmetric unlike non- uniform where both can be symmetric and non- symmetric. V IS constant in symmetric(uniform) but not in non-symmetric(uniform)

"Non-symmetric but uniformly distributed" is a contradiction.  "Uniformly distributed" means that the net charge density is the same everywhere inside the sphere.  If that's the case, then the charge distribution is automatically spherically symmetric, since rotating the sphere to any other orientation doesn't change the charge distribution—it's still the same everywhere.

Comment: very vague answer

Comment: @zappi:  I'm happy to elaborate on any part of it that you find unclear.  Please ask follow-up questions so I can address them.